# Which Doraemon episode is this with Shizuka and multiple mini Doraemons?

Tags: doraemon

[image: screenshot]

I have been looking for this episode for quite a while. I would appreciate anyone's help. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

- The text on the upper-left reads 「大晦日だよ！ドラえもん」(*Oomisoka dayo! Doraemon*, "It's New Year's Eve!! Doraemon"), which is the title of the show.
- The subtitle reads「人類を救うために、ドラ・ザ・仮面登場！！」 (*Jinrui wo sukuu tame ni, Dora The Kamen toujou!!*, "To save mankind, Dora The Kamen appears!!).

This is from **2001's Doraemon New Year's Eve special episode**, titled 「大晦日だよ！ドラえもん!!ミラクル大変身３時間スペシャル!!」 (*Oomisoka dayo! Doraemon!! Miracle Daihenshin 3-jikan Special!!*, "It's New Year's Eve! Doraemon!! Big Miracle Transformation 3-hour Special!!"). This special episode was broadcasted on 2001/12/31 from 18:00-20:54 JST and consists of 12 rerun episodes and 6 original bridging episodes:

1. ミニドラ救助隊 (Mini Dora Rescue Team) [Episode 1291]
2. 冬眠シェルター (Hibernation Shelter) [Episode 1342]
3. ドラえもん　の　捕物帖 (Doraemon's Detective Story)
4. ジャイアンのディナーショー (Gian's Dinner Show) [Episode 1054]
5. ドラえもん　の　荒野のガンマン (Doraemon's Desert Gunman)
6. 未来へのメッセージ (Message to the Future) [Episode 1247]
7. ドラえもん　の　黄門様 (Doraemon's Koumon-sama)
8. いつでもどこでもスケッチセット (Whenever, Wherever Sketch Set) [Episode 1053]
9. 刑事　ドラえもん (Inspector Doraemon)
10. ママのありがたみ    (Mama's Blessing) [Episode 1077]
11. ジュラ紀でドラミが大ピンチ (Jurassic Age, Dorami in Big Trouble) [Episode 1489]
12. ボクを止めるのび太 (Nobita Who Stops Me) [Episode 1472]
13. **ドラ・ザ・仮面 (Dora The Kamen)**
14. カードテレビ電話 (Card TV Telephone) [Episode 1420]
15. 特賞！のび太温泉 (Special Prize! Hot Spring Nobita) [Episode 1484]
16. 名探偵　ドラえもん (Detective Doraemon)
17. 雪だるまドラ太郎 (Snowman Dora-tarou)[Episode 1434]
18. 白雪姫のリンゴ (Snow White's Apple) [Episode 1300]

**Unfortunately, many Doraemon special episodes are only broadcasted on TV and don't have their home consumer version (DVD/BD), including this one.**

---

References:

- [TV Drama DB (Japanese)](http://www.tvdrama-db.com/drama_info/p/id-35565): Broadcast info
- [Hana Baloon (Japanese)](http://hanaballoon.com/dorachan/data/anime/ooyama/sp/sp2001.html): Episodes info