# Where can I watch the Doraemon New Year Special which aired on 31st December 2001?

Tags: doraemon

So I just figured in my previous question [Which Doraemon episode is this with Shizuka and multiple mini Doraemons?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/41522/which-doraemon-episode-is-this-with-shizuka-and-multiple-mini-doraemons) that I cannot get a DVD of this New Year Special.

I would like to know where I can watch these specials alternatively.

Comment: I doubt any of the [known legal sources](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/922) have a new year special from 16 years ago, but it might be worth the check. If not, considering there are no DVD's, I doubt we can point you to any _legal_ source to view it.